# How to make select box scrolled down by default with HTML or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have a select box with hours, it looks like that:

[image]

But I'd like to make it scrolled down by default after click, like that:

[image]

Is there any way I can achieve this with HTML or JS?

Answer (score 0):

.scrollTop() may work:

```
$('select').scrollTop(30);
```

And you can scroll to a particular element using this:

```
var $s = $('select');

var optionTop = $s.find('[value="3"]').offset().top;
var selectTop = $s.offset().top;

$s.scrollTop($s.scrollTop() + (optionTop - selectTop));
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kj9p4/

**Note:** does not work in Chrome.

Comment: That's not exactly what I expected, but we'll see, maybe it'll lead me to the right way

Comment: You can use just this line $('select').scrollTop(1000); I think its your solution

Comment: It doesn't seem to work - doesn't work on Chrome nor on Firefox.

Comment: Your fiddle contains example with just changing value without click, but I'd like to scroll it inside box after click.